# How to extract httpHeader in WebClient response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

How can I extract the parameter "session-id" from http header, and write it into the response?

```
webClient.post()
    .uri(host)
    .syncBody(req)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(MyResponse.class)
    .doOnNext(rsp -> {
        //TODO how can I access clientResponse.httpHeaders().get("session-id") here?
        rsp.setHttpHeaderSessionId(sessionId);
    })
    .block();

class MyResponse {
    private String httpHeaderSessionId;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible with `retrieve`. You need to use the `exchange` function instead of `retrieve`,

```
webClient.post()
    .uri(host)
    .syncBody(req)
    .exchange()
    .flatMap(response -> {
        return response.bodyToMono(MyResponse.class).map(myResponse -> {

            List<String> headers = response.headers().header("session-id");

            // here you build your new object with the response 
            // and your header and return it.
            return new MyNewObject(myResponse, headers);
        })
    });
}).block();

class MyResponse {
    // object that maps the response
}

class MyNewObject {
    // new object that has the header and the 
    // response or however you want to build it.
    private String httpHeaderSessionId;
    private MyResponse myResponse;
}
```

[Webclient Exchange](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-exchange)

Or with mutable object:

```
...
.exchange()
    .flatMap(rsp -> {
       String id = rsp.headers().asHttpHeaders().getFirst("session-id");
       return rsp.bodyToMono(MyResponse.class)
              .doOnNext(next -> rsp.setHttpHeaderSessionId(id));
    })
    .block();
```

Comment: This is not very elegant as I'd have to create an additional new object for each request... but works if that's the only possible solution.

Comment: well you need to do the exchange, then you can serialize the object and in a map function just do a setHeader on the current object but thats even uglier since the object will not be immutable.

Comment: What about the following approach? Would this be wrong? `.exchange().flatMap(rsp -> {String id = rsp.getHeaders().asHttpHeaders().getFirst("session-id"); return rsp.bodyToMono(MyResponse.class).doOnNext(next -> rsp.setHttpHeaderSessionId(id)); }).block();`

Comment: nothing is "wrong" per say, i just dont like having mutable objects but thats more of a programming taste.